# If the kernel of a matrix is the 0 vector, why is the basis of the kernel non existent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If the kernel of a matrix is the $0$ vector, why is the basis of the kernel non existent?

If I have the matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$

The kernel is the $0$ vector

Why is the basis of the kernel non-existent? Shouldn't the basis of the kernel be $0$?

Comment: It's not that the basis doesn't exit so much as the basis is the empty set, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Prospect I think made a typo. I know that the basis exists. I do not understand why the basis of the kernel in the matrix above does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. See Tony's comment.

Comment: A basis is a set of linearly independent vectors. A set of vectors is linearly independent if no nontrivial linear combination of them is zero. Therefore, $\{0\}$ is not a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 0):

This is by definition. The dimension is defined to be the minimum cardinality of the sets of vectors that span $V$. In the case $V=\{0\}$, we have that any set of vectors in this space will be linearly dependent and thus cannot be a basis.

Comment: If the kernel is the zero vector, why is "any set of vectors in this space" $linearly dependent$?

Comment: By space I meant the subspace $\{0\}$. The only vector in this subspace is 0 or no vectors, the emptyset.